# Best way to make QMake switch INCLUDEPATH on debug/release

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qmake

I have a Qt project (.pro) which has some dependencies that put the include directory in a "release" or "debug" directory when built. What is the best practice method of "switching" which directories are in the include in debug and release? At the moment I have this in my .pro:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    CONFIGURATION = debug
    DESTDIR = $${PWD}/../../Interface/Debug
} else {
    CONFIGURATION = release
    DESTDIR = $${PWD}/../../Interface/Release
}

GENDIR = $${DESTDIR}/Generated

OBJECTS_DIR = $${GENDIR}/obj
MOC_DIR = $${GENDIR}/moc
RCC_DIR = $${GENDIR}/rcc
UI_DIR = $${GENDIR}/ui

INCLUDEPATH += $(LIBOPC_DIR)/$${CONFIGURATION}/include
```

However if I import this into VS2012 via the Qt VisualStudio plugin it puts $(LIBOPC_DIR)/debug/include into both the debug and release configurations... am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of the VS plugin and/or qmake?

Comment: Not a solution to your immediate problem, but can you avoid switching include paths by including one include file which then includes one or the other include file, depending on whether "DEBUG" is defined?

Comment: Did you try to define INCLUDEPATH directly in the two CONFIG(...) blocks (i.e. in place of CONFIGURATION =)?